# Deserialize nested xml in c# (Unity-script)

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, deserialization

I am currently making a game in unity3D. I have a xml document which contains a number of decks which are populated with various playing cards. The xml-file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CardCollection>
  <Cards>
    <Deck DeckId="1">
      <Card Id="1">
        <CardElement1></CardElement1>
        <CardElement2></CardElement2>
      </Card>
      <Card Id="2">
        <CardElement1></CardElement1>
        <CardElement2></CardElement2>
      </Card>
      <Card Id="3">
        <CardElement1></CardElement1>
        <CardElement2></CardElement2>
      </Card>
    </Deck>
    <Deck DeckId="2">
      <Card Id="1">
        <CardElement1></CardElement1>
        <CardElement2></CardElement2>
      </Card>
    </Deck>
  </Cards>  
</CardCollection>
```

I have a class Card.cs which looks like the following:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Card {

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int id;

    [XmlElement("CardElement1")]
    public string cardElement1;

    [XmlElement("CardElement2")]
    public string cardElement2; 
}
```

And a class Deck.cs :

using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
public class Deck {

    [XmlAttribute("DeckId")]
    public int deckId;

    [XmlArray("Card")]
    public Card[] cards;
}
```

I'm using a class called CardContainer to populate a List decks with this information:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

[XmlRoot("CardCollection")]
public class CardContainer {

    [XmlArray("Cards")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Deck")]
    public List<Deck> decks = new List<Deck>();

    public static CardContainer Load(string path)
    {
        TextAsset xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CardContainer));

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml.text);

        CardContainer cards = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as CardContainer;

        reader.Close();

        return cards;
    }

}
```

I can get hold of the Id's of the decks using this snippet of code:

```
CardContainer cardContainer = CardContainer.Load(path);
foreach(Deck deck in cardContainer.decks){
       Debug.Log(deck.deckId);
}
```

However I have no idea how to deserialize and populate the Card-array in Deck objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the Deck class to the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Deck {

    [XmlAttribute("DeckId")]
    public int deckId;

    [XmlElement("Card")]
    public List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
}
```